# Override Jenkins Workflow

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I have a common Jenkins Workflow that looks like

```
def build() {
   echo "build"
}

def test() {
   echo "test"
}

def runAll() {
   build()
   test()
}

return this;
```

User code:

```
node {
   def flow = load(...)
   flow.runAll()
}
```

Is there any way to override flow method without reimplementing ones that use it? Something like

```
flow.metaClass.build = { -> echo "Custom build" }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are not using the `load` step, you may replace step functions with custom functions just by defining them. (The original step may be accessed as `steps.build` etc.)

I have not specifically tested the case of the overriding function being defined in a `load`ed script, but if it does not already work—and I presume you found it does not since you are asking this question, right?—I suspect you just need to qualify it like so: `this.build()`